# Disabling nodejs files in vsCode to client side js files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am having tremendous difficulty coding with java script. My Java script file is using nodejs, which means i cant perform any DOMS. For examples this code here:

```
var form = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-item');
console.log(form.length);
```

There are 4 nav-items which are displayed in the developer tools on the browser but the length is 0, where it should be 4. Why is this happening? Is there a way to disable nodejs or switch ? I know nodejs is server side, so how do i disable it or create another js file that is in client side?

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="boot.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="boot.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <!-- Creates the navbar links-->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Subjects</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link float-right" href="#">Sign Up</a>
                </li>     
              </ul>
            </div>  
          </nav>
          <br>
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox">Remember me
              </label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

BOOT.JS FILE:

```
var form = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-item');
console.log(form.length);
```

Comment: You say your javascript file is "using nodejs", but if it's running at all in the browser – and it is, because your call to `document.getElementsByClassName` is not throwing an error – then it's *not* running in node. So forget that. The problem is that your `getElementsByClassName` is not returning expected results. You need to provide the HTML and how the script is declared and run.

Comment: @seesharper I edited the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading your script at the end of the file instead of the header. The DOM has not loaded when you run the script. Either that or put it inside this event:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  var form = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-item');
  console.log(form.length);
});
```

Comment: What I don't get is why I see everyone code on a simple external js file and it works perfect for them when i do the same it doesn't work. The only solution I have seen is in vscode the JS simple for the file is yellow for me (maybe nodejs?) and blue for other. How can i disable nodejs?

Comment: Node has *nothing to do with it*. Your js file is loading and running and node is not involved. Please try the above and if it doesn't work, we'll work out why.

Comment: Why does this work? Every other person i see code doesnt include that first line and it works. This you have provided does work but makes 0 reason why the other way didnt when that is the norm/

Comment: @user218030 I don't know who "every other person is" but the fact is you need to have the DOM loaded before you can examine it. You can put the script last or use the above code. It makes perfect sense - the script runs as soon as it is loaded, but that is *before* the HTML has loaded.

Comment: So I need to put the ```<script src="boot.js"></script>``` at the end of the body?

Comment: Yes. Anything that examines the DOM needs to either wait for the DOM to load (jquery uses document.ready()), OR be loaded after the HTML.

Comment: I found the issue. I need to put the script outside the body not inside. My bad, thanks a lot!